# Skype not displaying content properly

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, skype

I am using Skype 4.3 on my Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. From past few days Skype is not working properly for me. The content are not being displayed properly. For example below is my call screen, also it flickers like a CRT

[image]

And confirm popup looks like this

[image]

The problem goes away when I restart the system, but again comes back after a few minutes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tryed reinstalling it

Comment: @Neil  yes I tried everything!

Comment: But nothing helped! :(

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same but this was when gnome-flashback has been installed once removed everything seemed to go back to normal. Try doing an update, upgrade and distribution upgrade. As this was broken by a gtk update.

Comment: Sorry can you please add commands in your answer, I am new to this. :(

Comment: OK Sure.

sudo apt-get update -y; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y;

The above will force an update it may be worth reinstalling ubuntu desktop aswell as you may have got something corrupted is the other issue that maybe here.

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 1):

This is look like `shmem` issue. Check:

```
$ ipcs -m -u
```

I have 4 GiB and 4096 units (the limit is!) when run Java application with bad Java version. Normally it was 100 MiB and near 40-50 units.

Check which process acquire `shmem` resources:

```
$ ipcs -m -p
$ ps -e | grep $PID
```

Check:

- [QT interfaces broken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696323/qt-interfaces-broken)
- [How to fix graphical issues with Skype, Gdk-WARNING?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692825/how-to-fix-graphical-issues-with-skype-gdk-warning)